# Swift 2 CLLocationManager Error

Tags: swift, swift2, cllocationmanager, cllocation

Saw a previous post on this but none of the solutions are working for me.

I am getting this error:

> Objective-C method 'locationManager:didUpdateLocations:' provided by
>   method 'locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)' conflicts with
>   optional requirement method 'locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)'
>   in protocol 'CLLocationManagerDelegate'

With the following code:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations.last
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Comment: just to confirm, have you included coreLocation framework `import CoreLocation`

Comment: voting to close, as not being reproducible

Answer (score 0):

Your problem cannot be reproduced. This is the *complete* contents of a Swift file in an iOS project on my machine; it compiles very happily under Swift 2.1:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit
class MapViewController : UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var mapView : MKMapView!
    var locationManager : CLLocationManager!
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations.last
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))
        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

Of course, that code wouldn't actually do anything (there is no actual map view); it's just some code. But there is no compiler error.

If you are still using an earlier version of Swift, update your copy of Xcode. If you are using Xcode 7.1, your error is inexplicable.